# Using https with library(pillow) in SICStus Prolog

Tags: https, prolog, sicstus-prolog

Recently, when I wanted to assemble and crunch some [StackOverflow meta data](https://api.stackexchange.com), using [`library(pillow)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dpillow.html#lib_002dpillow) appeared the right thing to me.

After the first toy uses (which worked ok), I encountered failure.
A quick peek into the sources suggests that the library does not support `https`. StackExchange sites, OTOH, do not offer access by `http`...

What can I do? (Apart from using some command line tools and invoking them to do the job.) Is there a more recent version of the library available which supports `https`?

I am using SICStus Prolog 4.5.0.

Comment: You could probably set up a local proxy that speaks http.